# model as r function's parameter, when calling the r function using rpy2 from multithreads

Tags: python, multithreading, r, multiprocessing, rpy2

This is more of a efficiency problem when calling r functions using rpy2 from multithreads.

The task of the r functions basically load a model file from disk and use the model to classify time series. However collecting the input time series is done using python by polling from the database (which will be updated by some web services). Once the python code detect a new time serial it will create a worker process, where rpy2 is used to call r functions to do the classification task.

Let python do the classification task is NOT an option for us. My main concern is the overhead when loading the model file. Clearly I do NOT want the file being read once each time a new time serial is classified. So the question is -

How can I load the model file just once, and the in-memory model object can be re-used when the same r function being called though rpy2?

My initial intention is load the model file into python and pass it as parameter each time the r function is called. But this will introduce extra cost of copying the model parameters (say the size is not negligible).

Your help will be very appreciated!

Comment: No, you can't. R is not multi-threaded and you need distinct R processes.

Comment: Perhaps using RServe?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, this is what I thought at first. But I did some test as mentioned by lgautier, and the code runs successfully. The R function was referred as global variable (as well as the model object), using rpy2. And this function object was shared by all the threads.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, another thought: define an R function/data object, and share among threads/processes, which is exactly the very nice thing about the functional programming style adopted by R. But I am not sure in my case, even the code runs correctly, was it distinct R processes being running or just one session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you:

1. have a function (classifier) written in R that requires a relatively large body of data to work (k nearest neighbors ?)
2. are loading that body of data using Python
3. would like to load the parameters /once/ and after that make as many calls to the classifier as required
4. plan passing the body of data as a parameter for the classifier

If following 4., copying is not always necessary but currently only if the data is numerical, or boolean, and the memory region is allocated by R.

However, I think that a simpler alternative for that situation is to have the body of data passed to R once for all (and copied if necessary) and use that converted object.

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
e1071 = importr('e1071')

from rpy2.robjects.conversion import py2ri

# your model's data are in 'm_data'
# here conversion is happening
r_m_data = py2ri(m_data)

for test_data in many_test_data:
    # r_m_data is already a pointer to an R data structure
    # (it was converted above - no further copying is made)
    res = e1071.knn(r_m_data, test_data)
```

This will correspond to what you describe as:

> How can I load the model file just once, and the in-memory model object can be re-used
>   when the same r function being called though rpy2?

Comment: Thanks, the key thing is the function, (i.e. e1071.knn) is called from worker threads (I use celery). But it does work even in the multiple thread scenario. All you need to do is define the r_m_data as global (actually the function object can be defined as global object as well). I marked your reply as answer

Comment: In the multithreaded scenario, what is happening is that Python's GIL is not released when calling the R function (here `knn`) and other thread have to wait until it returns. Rpy2 is not releasing the GIL during R calls because R is not able to multithread.

Comment: thanks you. I am just trying to clarify a bit: do you mean that there is actually no concurrency happens? But this is sort of contradict with my observation when using "celery" with rpy2. If I create one worker to process 50 test data it takes about 30 secs, but if I set the workers number to 10 it takes only 3-4 secs to finish the task....

Comment: hmm, just test my R function under R environment, take about 0.5 secs for each test_data. So there must be some concurrency going on here.

Comment: In your code (unfortunately not included with the question) `celery` is almost certainly using several /processes/, not /threads/. So yes, there is concurrency, but no, there is currently no multithreading possible with R.

Comment: Many thanks, this clarify my results/observations. You are right, documents of `celery` state that it use "process" by default not "thread"...